# stop robot.txt on the fly creation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I don't have a robots.txt file in my root folder but I can access it through example.com/robots.txt , it is shows this content:

```
       User-agent: *
       Disallow:
```

After some research on Google I learned that it is generated on the fly as my site is in wordpress. Can somebody help me stopping robot.txt on the fly creation in wordpress?

Comment: I'm not sure whether WP automatically generates robots.txt. Do you have a source for that? I was under the impression it doesn't. (It *does* generate `.htaccess` files if it's allowed to) Do you have some plug-in installed that does this?

Comment: Note also that `robot.txt` is not the same as `robots.txt` - only the latter has any effect on crawlers.

Comment: Also worth checking the selected theme's code, as I believe that can hook/filter the robots.txt request, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is generated in wp-includes/functions.php, line 1845 (in 3.3.1) and you can filter the result:

```
echo apply_filters('robots_txt', $output, $public);
```

So, if you don't want it to contain anything, can you add a filter and return an empty string. WordPress uses this in response to the blog/site's privacy setting (and $public gets set to '0' if the setting is to block search engines). Hope this helps!